# jQuery2 error by appending html after an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to append HTML after an element with this simple lines:
HTML to copy:

```
<div class="commentLayout">
    <form method="post" action="...">
        <textarea cols="10" rows="10" name="taCommentContent">
        </textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="newsId" value="">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">speichern</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is the JavaScript part that appends it:

```
function createComment (id)
{
    var $comment = $(".commentLayout").first().clone();
    $comment.removeClass("commentLayout").addClass("commentEdit");
    $comment.find("input[name=newsId]").first().val(id);
    $(this).after($comment);
}
```

In browser console (with source map) it shows me the following error:

```
jquery2x.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined
buildFragment @ jquery2x.min.js:3
domManip @ jquery2x.min.js:3
after @ jquery2x.min.js:
createComment @ frontend.js:716(anonymous function) @ VM219:1
```

I know what undefined means, but how came this error? I do not understand what went wrong here.
To clearify my question, I call this function from an link like this:

```
<!-- variable numbers comes from a loop -->
<a href="javascript:createComment(1);">comment this</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
$(this).after($comment);
```

The value of "this" is by default the window object. In the following snippet you may see a way to call your function and the value of "this" keyword.

In jQuery there is a possibility to change the context of a function:

```
$.proxy(createComment, this)(1);
```

and in javaScript you can use:

```
createComment.call(this, 1);
```

or

```
createComment.apply(this, [1]);
```

An alternative way is to pass as argument the "this" context variable to the function like in the snippet.

The snippet:

```js
function createComment (obj, id)
{
  var $comment = $(".commentLayout").first().clone();
  $comment.removeClass("commentLayout").addClass("commentEdit");
  $comment.find("input[name='newsId']").first().val(id);
  $(obj).after($comment);
  console.log('this is: ' + this + ' while obj is: ' + obj);
}

$(document).on('click', 'button[type="submit"]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  createComment(this, 1);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="commentLayout">
    <form method="post" action="...">
        <textarea cols="10" rows="10" name="taCommentContent">
        </textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="newsId" value="">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">speichern</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

You do not have any undefined value. Because the variable ***this*** is the window object you cannot insert ***after*** (jQuery) an object. You need a valid DOM object in order to apply the jQuery.after()....

New snippet using the anchor:

```js
function createComment (obj, id)
{
  var $comment = $(".commentLayout").first().clone();
  $comment.removeClass("commentLayout").addClass("commentEdit");
  $comment.find("input[name='newsId']").first().val(id);
  $(obj).after($comment);
  console.log('this is: ' + this + ' while obj is: ' + obj);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- variable numbers comes from a loop -->
<a href="javascript:createComment(document.getElementsByClassName('commentLayout')[0], 1);">comment this</a>
<div class="commentLayout">
    <form method="post" action="...">
        <textarea cols="10" rows="10" name="taCommentContent">
        </textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="newsId" value="">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">speichern</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer is still valid. In your link you can call your function in this way: createComment(this, 1); of course you need to change your function like in the snippet to: function createComment (obj, id).....

Comment: thanks, that made it. Sometimes JavaScript can be tricky. I use now this to call my function: `$(".aCreateComment").click(function(eventArgs) {
  var that = this;
  var id = parseInt($(that).attr("rel"));
  createComment(that, id);
 });`